# C++ implementation of Iterative Merge Sort crashing at large input sizes due to stack overflow

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stack-overflow, mergesort

I don't have much experience with a stack overflow, i thought they were caused by recursive functions exceeding a certain recursion depth, why would they occur here in this iterative implementation of the merge sort!

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define SIZE 3000000

    int L[2500002];
    int R[2500002];

    using namespace std;

    int min(int a, int b) {
        return !(b<a) ? a : b;
    }

    void Merge(int data[], int p, int q, int r)
    {
        if (q >= SIZE)q = (r + p) / 2;
        int sizeL = q - p + 2;
        int sizeR = r - q + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeL - 1; i++)
            L[i] = data[i + p];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeR - 1; i++)
            R[i] = data[i + q + 1];

        int max;
        if (L[sizeL - 2]>R[sizeR - 2])
            max = L[sizeL - 2] + 1;
        else
            max = R[sizeR - 2] + 1;
        L[sizeL - 1] = R[sizeR - 1] = max;

        int indexL = 0, indexR = 0;
        for (int i = p; i <= r; i++){
            if (L[indexL] <= R[indexR]){
                data[i] = L[indexL];
                indexL++;
            }
            else{
                data[i] = R[indexR];
                indexR++;
            }
        }


    }

    void MergeSort(int data[], int p, int r)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i< SIZE; i *= 2)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j += 2 * i)
                Merge(data, j, j + i - 1, min((j + 2 * i - 1), SIZE - 1));
    }
    /*****************************************************************************/

    bool IsSorted(int data[], int size)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i<(size - 1); i++)
        {
            if (data[i] > data[i + 1])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int data[SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            data[i] = rand();
        MergeSort(data,0,SIZE-1);
        if(IsSorted(data, SIZE))
            cout << "Sorted correctly";
        else
            cout << "incorrect sorting";
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: just a guess, out of memory? 4194305/1024 = 4096.00097656. Do you have 4GB of ram?

Comment: 4194304 is exactly 4 Gb. Maybe this rings some bell. Just a guess.

Comment: But the recursive version uses the same amount of memory so i don't see how that could be the case.

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself. Also construct a example program with **just** what is necessary - there's no point in having functions for quick-sort, insertion-sort or reading from input (input data can be hard-coded), for example.

Comment: @Dukeling the op posted the code. And how do you suggest to post a specific part of the code without knowing where the error is? The op stated clearly that this is the case.

Comment: @fonZ YES, he absolutely should do the debugging on his own. Every programmer should at least be able to find out where the error occurs. It's a bit of a waste of people's time to post 400 lines of code without *any* attempt to reduce it to the problematic part

Comment: @fonZ OP did post the code, but not **in the question itself** - having posts be dependent on external resources is not in line with trying to have [so] be a long-term self-contained knowledge base. OP already knows that the problem is with merge-sort, so I see absolutely no reason why the code for quick-sort or insertion-sort should be included - similarly most of the other code can probably also be removed. Replacing reading the input with hard-coding its generation is also a minor change reducing the amount of code and allowing anyone to test it with little to no effort.

Comment: @fonZ: Maybe I'm confused but why do you think that 4194305 `int` requires 4 GB of RAM? If you look at the linked code I only see four global `int` arrays that take up about 80 MB.

Comment: @MichaelWalz 4194304 is not 4GB; it's a little over 4 million.

Comment: @Dukeling Sorry i took so long to reply but i had to go out a bit, anyway i edited out the code that is specific to the problem.

Comment: Your current code probably faults because you are trying to define an array of 3000000 `int` inside `main()`. That is excessively large for automatic storage (stack).

Comment: You are right i was supposed to make it global, i thought this stack overflow issue is gonna be related to my original code but it's not in the original it was already defined as a global, but my iterative merge sort crashes after a certain input size, while my quick sort and recursive merge sort work just fine.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I had another completely different problem in the main code, but i suppose this particular question can be considered answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int data[SIZE];
    ...
```

declares the array on the stack.  There's a limit on stack size. It varies by OS and configuration but it could easily be less than 12 MB, the amount you're requesting (assuming 32-bit ints). Try allocating your array on the heap instead using a `std::vector`.

It's impossible for the compiler to warn you about this problem because stack size is set by the OS when it loads a program.  You could re-configure your OS to use a tiny stack by default and a program that worked before would suddenly start overflowing.

If you're interested in learning more about how the OS detects your stack overflow, look up virtual memory, MMUs and Guard Pages.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the issue, but [your merge sort seems buggy](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html).

Use unsigned integers instead of signed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class cSort_t
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void insertionSort (T* _array, const unsigned size);

    template <typename T>
    static void mergeSort(T *data, const unsigned size);

protected:
    cSort_t ();
    ~cSort_t ();
    cSort_t (const cSort_t& ref);
    const cSort_t& operator= (const cSort_t& ref);

private:
    template <typename T>
    _inline static void copyElements(T * dst,T * src, unsigned size);
};

//----------------- Insertion Sort --------------------
// standard insertion sort routine
template <typename T>
void cSort_t::insertionSort (T* _array, const unsigned size)
{ 
    T _temp;
    for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted<(int)size; ++unsorted)
    {
        _temp = *(_array+unsorted);
        for (int index = unsorted-1; index>=0; --index)
        {
            if (_temp < *(_array+index))
            {
                *(_array+index+1) = *(_array+index);
                if (0==index)
                     *_array = _temp;
            }
            else
            {
                *(_array+index+1) = _temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// copyElements - simple loop unrolling of data array copy
// to remove some overhead of looping.
template <typename T>
__inline void cSort_t::copyElements(T * dst, T * src, int size)
{
   while(size > 3)
   {
       *(dst+0) = *(src+0);
       *(dst+1) = *(src+1);
       *(dst+2) = *(src+2);
       *(dst+3) = *(src+3);
       dst+=4;
       src+=4;
       size-=4;
   };
   while(size > 0)
   {
       *dst++ = *src++;
       size--;
   };
}

//----------------- Merge Sort Function ----------------------
// A bottom's up iterative merge sort.
// Internal working buffer(temp[size]).
// Simple ping-pong buffering to reduce copy backs.
// Stable sort, maximum sort complexity=O(n*log n).
// Faster then most sorts for general purpose use.
// Returns the sorted result in the input buffer.
// Use: cSort_t::mergeSort(data_array, size_of_array);
// The reason for the speed up is simpler loops, pointer manipulation,
// no copy backs, recursive calls and storage re-creation. 
template <typename T>
void cSort_t::mergeSort(T *data, unsigned size)
{
    // use insertion sort for sorting small arrays
    if(size < 32) 
    {
        insertionSort (data, size);
        return;
    }

    unsigned int i,sp0c,sp1,sp1c;
    T *p0,*p1,*tmp,*tp1,*tp2;
    T *temp = new T [size];      // create an internal working temp

    // do easy first pass of bottoms up merge sort
    // calculate the number of passes used by algorithm to 
    // make the final sorted data end up back in input array to save moves.
    // by using either an initial in-place compare swap or a out-place compare move.
    i=0; for(unsigned j=1; j<size; j <<= 1) i++;   // 2**i >= size
    if(i&1)
    {
        // calculated odd number of passes
        // do the in-place compare and swap
        // to make last pass sorted data to end in the input buffer. 
        p0 = data;
        for(i=1; i<size; i+=2, p0+=2)
        {
            if(*p0 > *(p0+1)) {*temp = *p0; *p0 = *(p0+1);  *(p0+1) = *temp;}
        }
        tp1 = data;
        tp2 = temp;
    }
    else 
    {
        // calculated even number of passes
        // do an out of place compare and move 
        // to make last pass sorted data to end in the input buffer.
        p0 = data;
        p1 = temp;
        for(i=1; i<size; i+=2, p0+= 2, p1+= 2)
        {
            if(*p0 <= *(p0+1)) {*p1 = *p0; *(p1+1) = *(p0+1);}
            else {*p1 = *(p0+1); *(p1+1) = *p0;}
        }
        if(size&1) *p1 = *p0; // move last "odd" word
        tp1 = temp;
        tp2 = data;
    }
    // do more complex part of the bottoms up merge sort
    // instead of using a half way split use a binary split
    // only complication added is handing the right side element's remainder.
    //
    //      group 1          group n-1         group n 
    //  [ 5  9 | 7  2 ]   [ 3  6 | 4  9 ]   [ 7  6 | 5 ]
    //    ^      ^          ^      ^          ^      ^
    //   lsp    rsp        lsp    rsp        lsp    rsp        
    //
    p0 = tp1;   // p0 points to data elements be sorted 
    tmp = tp2;  // tmp points to where to put results this pass
    // for each pass of the bottoms up merge sort
    for(i=2; i<size; i<<=1)
    {
        p1 = p0 + i;     // calculate first groups' right side pointer
        sp1 = size - i;  // and number of elements past that pointer(inclusive)
        // do merge for all groups in this merge pass   
        for(;;)
        {
            sp0c = i;   // number of left side elements in group 
            sp1c = i;   // number of right side elements in group
            // on last group left and right lengths are different.
            if(sp1 < i) sp1c = sp1;
            // do a merge pass on a group
            for(;;)
            {
                if(*p0 <= *p1)   // simple compare merge pass
                {
                    *tmp++ = *p0++;   // move a left side element
                    if((--sp0c) == 0) break; 
                }
                else
                {
                    *tmp++ = *p1++;   // move a right side element
                    if((--sp1c) == 0) break;
                }
            }
            // we always have a few unmerged elements on left or right side  
            if(sp0c != 0)
            {
                // move what's remaining of left side's elements
                do {*tmp++ = *p0++;} while((--sp0c) != 0);
            }
            else
            {
                // move what's remaining of right side's elements
                do {*tmp++ = *p1++;} while((--sp1c) != 0);
            }
            p0 = p1;    // adjust left side and right side pointer
            p1 += i;    // for next group 
            if(sp1 <= (i<<1)) break;
            sp1 -= (i<<1);
        }
        // All groups processed except for possibly the last group 
        // because it may not have had a right side to sort.
        // if any remaining data copy it(partially sorted in previous passes)
        if(sp1 > i)
        {
            copyElements(tmp, p0, (sp1-i));
        }   
        // swap working pointers instead of copying temp array back to data array
        p0 = tp2;
        tmp = tp2 = tp1;
        tp1 = p0;
    }
    // delete internal working temp, sorted data should be back in input.
    delete [] temp;
}
```

Comment: please always explain what you are doing, add few lines of description before your code